# Applescript: Issue with number/number-word values

Tags: applescript

I have this so far:

```
    tell application "Finder"
set number_of_items to (count (every item of the desktop))
set correct_grammar to "" as text

if number_of_items is 1 then
    set number_of_items to "one" as text
end if

if number_of_items is greater than 1 then
    set s_letter to "s" as text
end if

set correct_grammar to "are" as text

if number_of_items is 1 then
    set correct_grammar to "is" as text
end if

if number_of_items is greater than 1 then
    set correct_grammar to "are"
end if

set s_letter to "s" as text
if number_of_items is 1 then
    set s_letter to "" as text
end if

tell application "System Events"
    display dialog "There " & correct_grammar & " " & number_of_items & " file" & s_letter & " in this folder." buttons {"Yes", "Exit"} with title "Test"
end tell
end tell
```

I am trying to make a dialog appear showing the text "one" instead of the number value of "1" Once I do this, the script makes it so it stops fixing the grammar. The portion of code below is what makes the issue occur but this is the whole intention of the correct grammar thing.

```
if number_of_items is 1 then
set number_of_items to "one" as text
end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code is correct, because the integer value of `number_of_items` is implicitly coerced to text, although it's a good habit to do that explicitly.

The code can be written a bit shorter:

```
tell application "Finder" to set number_of_items to (count items of desktop)

if number_of_items is 1 then
    set correct_grammar to "is"
    set number_of_items to "one"
    set s_letter to ""
else
    set s_letter to "s"
    set correct_grammar to "are"
end if

tell application "System Events"
    display dialog "There " & correct_grammar & " " & (number_of_items as text) & " file" & s_letter & " in this folder." buttons {"Yes", "Exit"} with title "Test"
end tell
```

**Edit**
If you are using Yosemite and higher you can use AppleScriptObjectiveC and Cocoa's `NSNumberFormatter` to create the number string

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set formatter to current application's NSNumberFormatter's alloc()'s init()
set numberStyle of formatter to 5 --  NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle

tell application "Finder" to set number_of_items to (count items of desktop)
if number_of_items is 1 then
    set correct_grammar to "is"
    set s_letter to ""
else
    set correct_grammar to "are"
    set s_letter to "s"
end if

set numberString to (formatter's stringFromNumber:number_of_items) as text

tell application "System Events"
    display dialog "There " & correct_grammar & " " & numberString & " file" & s_letter & " in this folder." buttons {"Yes", "Exit"} with title "Test"
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks man, worked like a charm! One more question, how could I do this for over 100 files?

Comment: actually there is no limit unless there is a particular grammar for files > 100

Comment: Would I need to copy/paste the code and change the number and the number-word each time until I got to 100?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're going to accomplish. if you want to check for other folders as the desktop replace the first line with `set sourceFolder to (choose folder)` `tell application "Finder" to set number_of_items to (count items of sourceFolder)`

Comment: No I mean replace the numbers. As in, when it shows 9, I'd rather it show "Nine" all the way up to 100.

Comment: I updated the post to provide an easy solution with AppleScriptObjC

Answer (score 0):

one second line of your script, you must coerc the number_of_items to a string :

```
set number_of_items to (count (every item of the desktop)) as string
```

and make your other tests "if" on the (count of every item of the Desktop)